# How Do I Remove Remote Disc from Finder (not in the Sidebar)

Tags: finder, imac, remote-disc

I've an iMac 10.10.3. When I open Finder and go to iMac under Devices I see my HDD, NAS, etc. But I also see "Remote Disc". I can't eject it (right click->Eject doesn't do anything) or trash it (The item "Remote Disc" can't be moved to the Trash because it can't be deleted).

I have absolutely no use for Remote Disc. So how can I remove it from Finder?

Note: Please note I'm not talking about removing it from the Sidebar. I've already done that.

Regards,

Comment: You cant eject remote disk. But you can look in to your sharing to see if it is enabled there. You have some Network settings that does that.

Comment: "System Preferences -> Sharing" does not have an item pertaining to CD/DVD/Remote Disc.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To remove:

1. Launch Terminal
2. Enter the following string:

   ```
   defaults write com.apple.NetworkBrowser EnableODiskBrowsing -bool false
   ```
3. Enter the following string:

   ```
   killall Finder
   ```

The icon should now be gone from both Finder and your sidebar. To reverse and make the icon show again, repeat the steps but run this command in step 2:

```
defaults delete com.apple.NetworkBrowser EnableODiskBrowsing
```

The icon is present on Macs which do not have optical drives but may still need access to the physical media from another computer.

Source: [Apple Support Forums](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2002127?start=15&tstart=0)

Comment: What are the implications of removing it?  Will it be impossible to connect to a remote disc after following these steps?

Comment: On 10.13.x It's also showing up for all Macs, even ones with built in dvd drives.

Answer (score 2):

check out the Finder preferences. {click the Finder, go to the top menu bar and click the Finder drop-down, choose preferences.}

if that doesn't do it, I'm not sure it can be removed?
it's also possible that you might be able to turn it off in System Preferences.

if that doesn't work you are looking at some sort of terminal setting, and I don't know what that is yet.

I will have to boot over to 10.10 and see what this is all about. my suspicion is that you are seeing the all drives list which won't be able to be changed.

Comment: I'm not finding anything relevant in Finder preferences. Here's a screenshot which shows better what I'm trying to remove: http://monosnap.com/image/vmRzNWMJh7oKx9dFGVzT0enR9F865h

Answer (score -2):

You can right click on it and on the menu select Remove from Sidebar

Comment: "*Note: Please note I'm not talking about removing it from the Sidebar. I've already done that.*"